# How can I solve this problem with loops in C?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, while-loop, logic

**Hello everyone, I have a problem that I can't solve, maybe something trivial!**

I need to automate this piece of code with loops:

```
                array[1]=arrayPayload[0].bytes[0];
                array[2]=arrayPayload[0].bytes[1];
                array[3]=arrayPayload[0].bytes[2];
                array[4]=arrayPayload[0].bytes[3];
                array[5]=arrayPayload[1].bytes[0];
                array[6]=arrayPayload[1].bytes[1];
                array[7]=arrayPayload[1].bytes[2];
                array[8]=arrayPayload[1].bytes[3];
```

I tried this solution, but obviously it doesn't work because the indexes don't scroll correctly!

```
    for(x=1 ; x < 9 ; x++){
        for(u=0 ; u < 2 ; u++){
            for(z=0 ; z < 4 ; z++){
                array[x] = arrayPayload[u].bytes[z];
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance if you can help me!!

Comment: What you want to do ?

Comment: In your question, you are indexing into `array` using indexes `1` to `8`. Is this intended? Or did you mean `0` to `7`?

Comment: @mingo Are all the variables arrays? Or are some of them pointers?

Comment: @mingo Regarding your edit, the [closed] status is for questions that are unclear and need to be improved by the poster. Some questions end up like that when other users cast 3 close votes. That's not the case here, your question is ok. If you think the matter is resolved and you've accepted an answer, then you can leave it at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want x+1 after each assignment so it does not make sense to put the x increment at the outer-most loop.

```
    x=1;
    for(u=0 ; u < 2 ; u++){
        for(z=0 ; z < 4 ; z++){
            array[x++] = arrayPayload[u].bytes[z];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nor does it make sense to use 3 iterators when only 1 is needed.

Comment: @Lundin better readability and I think it's clearer this way to show where the original code went wrong

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution utilizes the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (as opposed to "keep it stupidly complicated"). Always keep loops as trivial as possible. Iterate from zero to a known value. Don't use multiple iterators when there's no need for it.

```
for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  array[i+1] = arrayPayload[0].bytes[i];
}
for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  array[i+5] = arrayPayload[1].bytes[i];
}
```

When possible, swap the "magic numbers" for meaningful named constants. I have no idea what this data is, but production quality code would looking something along the lines of:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<SET_SIZE; i++)
{
  array[i+OFFSET0] = arrayPayload[SET0].bytes[i];
}
for(size_t i=0; i<SET_SIZE; i++)
{
  array[i+OFFSET1] = arrayPayload[SET1].bytes[i];
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... so the day that `arrayPayload` changes from 2 to 4 elements, you would make 4 loops?

Comment: @4386427 If I had any form of information of the nature of the data, I would write the code accordingly. If I don't, then I'd write it as simple and readable as possible. Code repetition is fine if it's just these two little data sets, less so if there's lots of them.

Comment: Well, you got a point and I wont DV. But I would never do like this myself. The "overhead" and/or complexicity of nested loops are (IMO) very low. The benefit of writing "easy to maintain" code is much bigger.

Comment: @4386427 Normally array access would start at index 0 and then it would make sense to use multiple loops. But since this code uses weird, non-trivial indices, I didn't write it like that. In this case it is kind of self-documenting code. It is kind of the point to get the reader to think "why is he writing 2 loops".

Answer (score 0):

Your "problem" is that `x` is incremented in the outer loop so you get:

```
x u z
-----
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 0 2
1 0 3
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 0 0
2 0 1
2 0 2
2 0 3
2 1 0
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 1 3
...
8 0 0
8 0 1
8 0 2
8 0 3
8 1 0
8 1 1
8 1 2
8 1 3
```

So all elements of `array` end up being equal to `arrayPayload[1].bytes[3]`.

Simply drop the outer loop and increment `x` after each assignment.

If all the variables `array`, `arrayPayload`, `bytes` are arrays (i.e. none of them are pointers) you should do:

```
#define ARRAY_OFFSET 1
#define ELM_ARRAY (sizeof array / sizeof array[0])
#define ELM_PAYLOAD (sizeof arrayPayload / sizeof arrayPayload[0])
#define ELM_BYTES (sizeof arrayPayload.bytes / sizeof arrayPayload[0].bytes[0])


// Optional assert to make sure 'array' size is ok
assert(ELM_ARRAY >= (ELM_PAYLOAD * ELM_BYTES + ARRAY_OFFSET);

x = ARRAY_OFFSET;
for (size_t i = 0; i < ELM_PAYLOAD; ++i)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < ELM_BYTES; ++j)
    {
        array[x] = arrayPayload[i].bytes[j];
        ++x;
    }
}
```

Calculating the loop condition from the actual array sizes will make your code easier to maintain in case one of the arrays change size.

In case one or more of `array`, `arrayPayload`, `bytes` are pointers, you should give the number of element - and thereby the loop-condition - using a define, e.g. `#define ELM_PAYLOAD 2`

An alternative approach using `memcpy`:

```
#define ARRAY_OFFSET 1
#define ELM_ARRAY (sizeof array / sizeof array[0])
#define ELM_PAYLOAD (sizeof arrayPayload / sizeof arrayPayload[0])
#define SZ_BYTES_ELEMENT (sizeof arrayPayload[0].bytes[0])
#define ELM_BYTES (sizeof arrayPayload.bytes / SZ_BYTES_ELEMENT)

// Optional assert to make sure 'array' size is ok
assert(ELM_ARRAY >= (ELM_PAYLOAD * ELM_BYTES + ARRAY_OFFSET);

for (size_t i = 0; i < ELM_PAYLOAD; ++i)
{
    memcpy(array + i * ELM_BYTES + ARRAY_OFFSET, 
           arrayPayload[0].bytes, 
           ELM_BYTES * SZ_BYTES_ELEMENT);
}
```

Comment: Generally well thought out, my preference would be to get the `sizeof arrayPayload.bytes / sizeof arrayPayload[0].bytes[0]` out of the loop in a const. I find this is easier to read. And maybe faster depending whether the compiler stores the ending condition or calculates it evey time.

Comment: @KamiKaze Well, it's ok to move the size calculation out of the loop condition. However, remember that `const int` in C can **not** be a compile time constant like it can in C++. But once the compiler applies optimization it doesn't really matter much...

Comment: No need but your comparison might be calcuated every iteration, which would be slower than saving it after the first. I do not know which compiler would compile this away with whatever optimization. I would expect the ancient one that I have to use would not optimize it.

Comment: @KamiKaze No, the `sizeof` things will be handled at compile time (except for VLA) - no worries

Comment: @KamiKaze Any sane compiler handles the division as well

Comment: @KamiKaze Changed to to use defines so that the loop condition is easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible solution

```
 for(int i = 1 ; i < 9; i++) {
        array[i] = arrayPayload[(i-1)/4].byte[(i-1) -(((i-1)/4) * 4)];
    }
```

Comment: This seems way to complex

Answer (score -2):

```
int x,y,z;
for(x=1 ; x < 9 ; x++){
  y= (x-1) / 4;
  z= (x-1) % 4;
  array[x] = arrayPayload[y].bytes[z];  
}
```

It's a bit tricky because the indicies don't line up well (x is one step ahead).
But you can do this with division and modulus 4 quite easily.

As you progress through one array `array`, you just need one loop the rest is dependant on the position in the array, so you should use `x` as a reference for the rest.

Maybe it is easier to read and for the compiler to change it to:

```
int x;
for(x=0 ; x < 8 ; x++){
  const int y= x / 4;
  const int z= x % 4;
  array[x+1] = arrayPayload[y].bytes[z];  
}
```

Comment: But why add all this needless complexity? It only makes the code _far_ harder to read and possibly _far_ slower, if the compiler fails to optimizes away the division.

Comment: @Lundin My premise was that this might go further then just only to index 9 and then this scales quite nice in terms of additional work, while your solution would require more loops added for every set (or another loop to iterate the sets). Still for the given length I think your solution is better. Especially avoiding magic numbers is very good advice.

Comment: There's not enough info to make any assumptions about the nature of the data.

Comment: @Lundin Would you consider the 2nd version an improvement? And yes I was stating that I had this premise for me, not sure this would be necessary.

Comment: No, because there's absolutely no need to involve division here.

Comment: @Lundin I appreciate the feedback

Answer (score -3):

Remove the outermost loop and calculate the array index from the two inner counters instead:

```cpp
array[u * PAYLOAD_SIZE/BYTE_NUMBER + z + 1]
```

Or, an overall simpler approach would be to have *one* loop and count from 0 to `PAYLOAD_SIZE` excluding, and then calculate the rest from this counter:

```cpp
array[i + 1] = arrayPayload[i / BYTE_NUMBER].bytes[i % BYTE_NUMBER]
```